# Android Autocomplete Editext remove Suggestions Duplications

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have Auto-complete Box in Android, i am filling this Auto-complete Box with the names of Some list retrieved from the Server.

Suppose i Have ABC, XYZ, PQR, ABCC, ABCCD etc... Now on First Suggestion when i type AB: It should give me ABC, ABCC, ABCCD. Now i have selected ABC..
(Autocomplete in multivalue separated by ;)
NOw when i write ABC: It Again give ABC, ABCC, ABCCD..

Result i Want: on ABC select should be removed from the Autocomplete list. so Next suggestion should be ABCC, ABCCD only not ABC.

Please Help me out

Thanks in Advance..

Code from comment below:

```
myAutoComplete = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.talksender);
myAutoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, names));
```

Comment: This is AutoComplete EditText property so you have to maintain your stored listing filter.

Comment: Use a custom adapter that implements `Filterable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to keep track of the selected items.
2. When creating the filtered list you need to filter by the string typed into the EditText AND by the items already selected.

For filtering your ArrayAdapter you need to:

1. Create a `Filter` implementaion which performs the filtering based on the EditText input AND the already selected items.
2. Override your ArrayAdapter's `getFilter()`  method to return your custom `Filter` implementation

Comment: Yes Thanks but my main problem is that where should i filter it as for Autocomplete we give the resource list now.. How to handle that selected item. and Check.. Because as it is Multivalue it ll use same resource to give suggestions. So i am having problem to refactor how to proceed..

Comment: `myAutoComplete = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.talksender);              myAutoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());                    names = Arraylist(); // i Fill this names Field with collection of names of ppl from the Database and also the Server Webservice.                             myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, names));` Now my names field have many values which i gave to Autocomplete so where can i set a Filter in Between ..

Comment: please see my update. you really need to read something about `Filter`  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html